# NextJS Middleware causing "redirected you too many times" error in prod

Tags: next.js, middleware

I just implemented email/password authentication into my locally hosted NextJS, but it stops working only in production; running it locally works perfectly.

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "https://example.com.br" : "http://localhost:3000"
  const token = cookies().get("access_token")
  
  if(!token && url + "/" !== request.url) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url))
  if(token && request.url === url) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.url))

  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/dashboard", "/:path", "/marketplace", "/redirect" ],
}
```

I've already tried to refactor the middleware, I've tried to reconfigure the middleware, see if there was any log, researched, and so on, Obs: is nextjs14

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're redirecting infinitely.

The result of `new URL("/", "https://example.com")` is `https://example.com`, *not* `https://example.com/`. So you keep redirecting and `url + "/" !== request.url` ends up never being true.

Try removing the  `+ "/"` part and changing the line to

```
if(!token && url !== request.url) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", request.url))
```

Comment: Actually, it's returning as "http://localhost:3000/" instead of "http://localhost:3000," so instead of adding the URL + /, I placed the / directly in the URL string, and also added "www" to the production URL and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "https://www.duplormaquinas.com.br/" : "http://localhost:3000/"
  const token = cookies().get("access_token")?.value
  if(!token && url !== request.url) return NextResponse.redirect(url)
  else if(token && request.url === url) return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", request.url))

  return NextResponse.next()
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/dashboard", "/marketplace", "/redirect", "/:path"],
}
```